# Oracle: how to select timestamped value for particular date

Tags: sql, oracle

### Name, Salary, DateChanged

John     100     '10-Jan-2017'

John      200     '20-Jan-2017'

John      50      '20-Jan-2018'

Tom       100     '10-Jan-2017'

Tom       200     '20-Jan-2017'

Alice     100     '10-Jan-2017'

Alice     200     '20-Jan-2017'

How to get persons with salary > 100 on Apr,1, 2018?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by datechanged desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where datechanged <= date '2018-04-01'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and salary > 100;
```

This selects all rows before the cutoff date.  It then enumerates them and chooses the one with the highest date and compares the salary.

This assumes that the first salary is in the table.